# How to duplicate a socket in Java (transfer to another thread)?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, transfer

A short history: I have a server app (telnet to be more precisely) written in C# that opens a new socket and a new thread for each client that connect, like:

```
Socket newsock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
Socket clientSocket = newsock.Accept();
Thread _connection = new Thread();
....
```

After the user opens a connection, it is asked for credentials (username and password) and then one can do some actions against a database. A main feature is that, if the same user tries to connect from different devices, the connection is always transferred to the newly created thread and the other device gets disconnected, like:

```
if (runningThread.UserID == Username.Value)
{
    SocketInformation _infoSock = runningThread.clientSocket.DuplicateAndClose(Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id);
    Socket _oldSocket = runningThread.clientSocket;
    newThread.clientSocket = new Socket(_infoSock); 
    _oldSocket.Close();
}
```

Now, I have to do the same thing in JAVA, and the big question is: how do I do this? As far as I looked and found until now, there is no equivalent in Java for DuplicateAndClose!

**Edit**

After reading some posts and comments I thought it is better to explain what I need to achieve:

let's say at moment t1, user John is using device A to connect to the server. The server creates session 1 "talking" on socket 1. Later on, at moment t2, same user John is using device B (e.g. another computer) to connect to the server. The server creates session 2 that "talks" on socket 2, and asks John for his username and password (which are not known at the moment the server creates the anonymous session). At moment t3, when John gives his credentials to the server the session is not anonymous anymore.

Now, the server identifies John and the fact he already has a running session, and needs to "transfer" the existing session to device B. Since a working session is not something easy to duplicate, the best way to do the transfer is to direct session 1 to "talk" with device B after t3 moment.

In C# it works by duplicating socket 2 and giving it to session 1, but in Java I did not find such functionality. So the question again: how do I do this in Java?

many thanks to any useful answer!

Comment: You have a new socket, right?  From the new connection from the new device?  Why not just close the existing one and replace this thread's clientSocket with the new one?

Comment: I don't actually understand this question. What do you want "transferred"? The IO blocking? The state?

Comment: The connection isn't 'transferred to the newly opens device'. The newly connected device has its own thread with its own connection. According to your description, the prior one gets closed. That's it.

Comment: "replace this thread's clientSocket with the new one" - how do I do this? Simply writing runningThread.clientSocket = newThread.clientSocket does not work, I need somehow to create a copy of the existing socket and give it to the existing thread.

Answer (score 4):

> there is no equivalent in Java for DuplicateAndClose

Per this: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.duplicateandclose(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.duplicateandclose%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) DuplicateAndClose deals with making a socket available across processes.  This is not the same thing as doing it across threads.   If you are using multiple threads in Java (likely) rather than multiple processes, you can just use the Socket object directly - you don't need any sort of DuplicateAndClose call for whatever you are doing.

And if the problem is that you are trying to have another connection from the same client act like it has already logged in based on another earlier connection - that really has nothing to do with sockets - that's a matter of your internal application state.  Make a synchronized map of your clients that have connected and write the logic you need.

Comment: Well, this takes me back to my question. "you can just use the Socket object directly" - how do I do this? Simply writing 'runningThread.clientSocket = newThread.clientSocket' does not work, I need somehow to create a copy of the existing socket and give it to the existing thread.

Comment: What about that does not work?  You most definitely can pass the socket object around and read and write to/from it from various places in your code (although you'll want to take care that you don't have two things writing to it at once).

Comment: Please have a look at my edit. Yes, you can pass around a socket and do whatever you want with it as long as you do not want to change it. But when you want to replace an existing socket with another one (like in my question, where a session should change from one device to another) it does not work. Sockets cannot simply changed by an a=b operation. That's why the DuplicateAndClose method in C#.